# Event manager in Model/View/Controller context

Tags: java, swing, events, model-view-controller

By the reference to a question that I've asked for separating event processing from the view, And put in separate class: [JAVA form detect change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822613/java-form-detect-change/27822668#27822668)

What relation between controller and events manager class? And how do it in a way that don't violate the Model/View/Controller design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The swing MVC model is loosely based but not strictly based on the traditional MVC model. In swing, the view and controller parts collapses into a single UI (User-Interface) object. Simply saying the controller is built into the view. Going through some of the articles on MVC and MVC with Swing examples would help. Here are some references I found good - [Model View Controller with Java Swing](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1524), [A Java Model View Controller example](http://alvinalexander.com/ooa-ood/java-model-view-controller-mvc-example-1) and [A Swing Architecture Overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html#delegate).